# Is there a way in pyspark to count unique values

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe (12m x 132) and I am trying to calculate the number of unique values by column, and remove columns that have only 1 unique value.

So far, I have used the pandas nunique function as such:

```
import pandas as pd

df = sql_dw.read_table(<table>)
df_p = df.toPandas()

nun = df_p.nunique(axis=0)
nundf = pd.DataFrame({'atr':nun.index, 'countU':nun.values})

dropped = []
for i, j in nundf.values:
  if j == 1:
    dropped.append(i)
    df = df.drop(i)
print(dropped)
```

Is there a way to do this that is more native to spark - i.e. not using pandas?

Comment: you can use countDistinct function in spark

Comment: @dassum could you provide an example that removes columns with only one unique value using countDistinct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look at the commented example below. The solution requires more python as pyspark specific knowledge.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
#creating a dataframe
columns = ['asin' ,'ctx' ,'fo' ]

l = [('ASIN1','CTX1','FO1')
,('ASIN1','CTX1','FO1')
,('ASIN1','CTX1','FO2')
,('ASIN1','CTX2','FO1')
,('ASIN1','CTX2','FO2')
,('ASIN1','CTX2','FO2')
,('ASIN1','CTX2','FO3')
,('ASIN1','CTX3','FO1')
,('ASIN1','CTX3','FO3')]

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)

df.show()
#we create a list of functions we want to apply
#in this case countDistinct for each column
expr = [F.countDistinct(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns]

#we apply those functions
countdf =  df.select(*expr)
#this df has just one row
countdf.show()

#we extract the columns which have just one value
cols2drop = [k for k,v in countdf.collect()[0].asDict().items() if v == 1]
df.drop(*cols2drop).show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+----+---+
| asin| ctx| fo|
+-----+----+---+
|ASIN1|CTX1|FO1|
|ASIN1|CTX1|FO1|
|ASIN1|CTX1|FO2|
|ASIN1|CTX2|FO1|
|ASIN1|CTX2|FO2|
|ASIN1|CTX2|FO2|
|ASIN1|CTX2|FO3|
|ASIN1|CTX3|FO1|
|ASIN1|CTX3|FO3|
+-----+----+---+

+----+---+---+
|asin|ctx| fo|
+----+---+---+
|   1|  3|  3|
+----+---+---+

+----+---+
| ctx| fo|
+----+---+
|CTX1|FO1|
|CTX1|FO1|
|CTX1|FO2|
|CTX2|FO1|
|CTX2|FO2|
|CTX2|FO2|
|CTX2|FO3|
|CTX3|FO1|
|CTX3|FO3|
+----+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

My apologies as I don't have the solution in pyspark but in pure spark, which may be transferable or used in case you can't find a pyspark way.

You can create a blank list and then using a foreach, check which columns have a distinct count of 1, then append them to the blank list.

From there you can use the list as a filter and drop those columns from your dataframe.

```
    var list_of_columns: List[String] = ()

    df_p.columns.foreach{c => 
      if (df_p.select(c).distinct.count == 1)
         list_of_columns ++= List(c)

    df_p_new = df_p.drop(list_of_columns:_*)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can group your df by that column and count distinct value of this column:

```
df = df.groupBy("column_name").agg(countDistinct("column_name").alias("distinct_count"))
```

And then filter your df by row which has more than 1 distinct_count:

```
df = df.filter(df.distinct_count > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import approx_count_distinct
# Count the approximate number of distinct elements in the 'column_name' column
distinct_count = DataFrameFromSQL.select(approx_count_distinct('column_name')).collect()[0][0]
print(f"There are approximately {distinct_count} distinct elements in the 'column_name' column.")
```